# New Measure in Power BI - column name not recognized

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have a table in Power BI named 'Data' which contains a field named 'Carrier'.

I need to create a new measure that would be similar to the following I have in SQL:

case
when carrier NOT IN
('UA' , 'LH' , 'LX' , 'OS' , 'SN' , 'AA' , 'IB' , 'BA' , 'AY' , 'AS' , 'B6' , 'DL' , 'AF' , 'KL' , 'VS' , 'WN')
then 'Other'
else carrier

However I don't know the proper syntax.
Please assist.
Thank you!

Comment: Your question title contains an error from a measure you have tried. Share this as a starting point. Add sample data as a table and provide an example of what your desired end visual would look like using that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You need a switch statement.

- Right click on the table with the data
- New measure

```
    NewMeasure = SWITCH('TableName'[Carrier}],
    "UA", "UA",
        "LH", "LH",
        "LX", "LX",
        "OS", "OS",
        "SN", "SN",
        "AA", "AA",
        "IB", "IB",
        "BA", "BA",
        "AY", "AY",
        "AS", "AS",
        "B6", "B6",
        "DL", "DL",
        "AF", "AF",
        "KL", "KL",
        "VS", "VS",
        "WN", "WN",
        "Other"
    )
```

It checks the Carrier field and returns the same value if i's in one of the specified carrier codes.  If the value isn't in the list, then it returns 'Other'.

I highly recommend checking out Dax Patterns below and reading the documentation if you're going to be using PowerBI.  It will save you a ton of time.
[Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/.)
[Dax Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/.)